# Mongoose/MongoDB: Sum up integers in keys

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have such a data structure in Mongoose, resp. MongoDB:

```
{
 id: abc
 data: {
   subData: 1.23
  }
}
```

Now I want to sum up all `data.subData` keys where id: "abc".

So later express will send to the client the sum of all integers stored in subData in my database, e.g. `128912731.2712312`. I read that this is possible with aggregation and projections in MongoDB, but is it possible natively in Mongoose with one handy method?

Source: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-with-user-preference-data/

Comment: Are we talking of `id` or `_id`? In general, it makes more sense to use the Aggregation framework, as it tends to be faster, especially when talking of sharded clusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregation framework [exists in mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.aggregate) as well:

```
MyModel
    .aggregate()
    .match({id: "abc"})
    .group({
        _id: null,
        subData: { $sum: "$data.subData" }
    })
    .exec(callback);
```

Side note: Integers are whole numbers. The numbers you're talking about in your question are [floats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)

Comment: Worked. Is this new in Mongoose 3.x ?

Comment: Yeah, it [looks like it was added in 3.7](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/commit/cd69a7a7d7a2ecda852e29784f3ca3822779c6ab)